# How to use htaccess to rewrite urls in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am new to cakephp and I want to change my project's admin from `'websiteurl/admin'` to something unique and different as per client requirement. But the problem is that I cannot do that from routes file as it can create some issues in the project. So I thought to do that using htaccess. But htaccess is not rewriting urls. My project directory is `www/html/myproject/`

Here's what config I've done-
1. Enabled mod_rewrite using `sudo a2enmod rewrite.`
2. Added

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All


    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

in file- `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

For testing purpose I created a test.html file in `www/html/myproject/webroot/` 
and here's my htaccess code in webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^testfile$ test.html [NC]
</IfModule>
```

## below code added to increase file upload size

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

But When I access the projecturl/testfile Cakephp gives error that TestFileController could not be found.

Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong in using htaccess and also will it be good to use htaccess rather than routes file to change admin url? Thank you.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the `a2enmod`?

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting apache many times after the configuration.

Comment: You cannot put stuff after an all catching `[L]`ast rule.

Comment: @ndm I added my code above that line but still not working.